# How to use "onReadError/onWriteError" in "ReaderListener/WriterListener" to handle exceptions

Tags: spring-batch

It just throws an exception and does not run "onReadError"

PS: mst_employees1 is a data table that does not exist to simulate anomalies

```
    @Bean
    private Step step1(MyBatisCursorItemReader<MstEmployeesEntity> myBatisReader,FlatFileItemWriter<MstEmployeesEntity> CSVWriter){
        return stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step1")
                .listener(stepListener)
                .<MstEmployeesEntity,MstEmployeesEntity>chunk(1)
                .reader(myBatisReader)
                .listener(readerListener)
                .processor(myPorcessor)
                .writer(CSVWriter)
                .build();
    }
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public MyBatisCursorItemReader<MstEmployeesEntity> myBatisReader(@Value("#{jobParameters['para1']}") Integer pk) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("employeePk",pk);
        return new MyBatisCursorItemReaderBuilder<MstEmployeesEntity>()
                .sqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactory)
                .queryId("jp.armg.toughness.datasource.mapper.BatchMstEmployeesEntityMapper.exmapleSelect")
                .parameterValues(map)
                .build();
    }
```

Job Class

```
public class ReaderListener implements ItemReadListener<MstEmployeesEntity> {

    @Override
    public void onReadError(Exception ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        System.out.println("on read error: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("======================================");
    }
}
```

Read Listener

```
<mapper namespace="jp.armg.toughness.datasource.mapper.BatchMstEmployeesEntityMapper">
    <select id="exmapleSelect" resultType="jp.armg.toughness.datasource.entity.MstEmployeesEntity">
        select * from mst_employees1 where employee_pk &lt; #{employeePk};
    </select>
</mapper>
```

Mapper

```
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:152) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ebb633d0.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.1.2.RELEASE.jar:4.1.2.RELEASE]
```

Console

It just throws an exception and does not run "onReadError"

PS: mst_employees1 is a data table that does not exist to simulate anomalies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> mst_employees1 is a data table that does not exist to simulate anomalies

This kind of anomalies should be checked in a fail-fast manner, at the time of initializing the reader (as the current behaviour) and not at the time of reading items. The `ItemReadListener` is designed for errors that might happen during item reading and not during the initialization of the reader.

So if you really want to write a unit test for such case, your test should try to initialize a reader with a non existing table and expect an `ItemStreamException`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Can you provide a simple example of catching this exception?

Comment: @Mahmoud Ben Hassine , Can you please help how to skip when an exception like FlatFileParseException occurs in reader.

Comment: You can find an example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/skip/SkippableExceptionDuringReadSample.java. You just need to add a `SkipListener` and implement `onSkipInRead`.